# Background color on text only

Tags: html, css

New to HTML. I have this code in css

```
h1 {text-align: center;
background: white;
}
```

I wanted to make a white background only on my text, but the color is from the one end of the page to the other. I want the background to be same width as my text. Any advices ?

Comment: `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: ^ or `display:table` if you want to keep it on its own line.

Comment: Tried putting them, it removes the white background now

Comment: share a full code so we can see the issue

Comment: It's the same like on the post with 'display:table' added

Comment: it's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/8r4cunmj/

Comment: In the fiddle, the h1 is not centered any more. If that is the problem, add `margin:1rem auto;` to the CSS. But as @TemaniAfif says, it does work otherwise. Are you sure you didn't have a typo when adding the display value?